# Force decay of string literals (const char array) to ptr

Tags: c++, string-literals, string-view, emplace

In the following example I try to `emplace_back()` a string literal and a `string_view` into an `std::pair` of `string_views`. However, my problem is that `emplace_back()` takes up the string literal as a const char array and doesn't decay it to a pointer. The consequence is that `emplace_back()` can't find `std::string_view`'s const char* constructor. How can I decay string literals manually as parts of function arguments (that are aggressively gobbled up by universal references)?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:32,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:32,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:32,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:32,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++std::string_view+vsn_+%3D+%220.0.1%22%3B%0A++++std::string_view+key_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aauto+get_url(A+params+%3D+%7B%7D)%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::pair%3Cconst+char*,+std::string_view%3E%3E+queries%3B%0A++++if+(!!params.key_.empty())+%7B%0A++++++++queries.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct,+(%22key%3D%22),+params.key_)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++if+(!!params.key_.empty())+%7B%0A++++++++queries.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct,+(%22VSN%3D%22),+params.vsn_)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++std::string+url%3B%0A++++for+(auto+q+:+queries)+%7B%0A++++++++%0A++++++++url+%2B%3D+q.first%3B%0A++++++++url+%2B%3D+q.second.data()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+url%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22%25s%22,+get_url().data())%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.31070496083551,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.689295039164485,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <cstdio>


struct A
{
    std::string_view vsn_ = "0.0.1";
    std::string_view key_;
};

auto get_url(A params = {})
{
    std::vector<std::pair<const char*, std::string_view>> queries;
    if (!params.key_.empty()) {
        queries.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, ("key="), params.key_);
    }
    if (!params.key_.empty()) {
        queries.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, ("VSN="), params.vsn_);
    }
    std::string url;
    for (auto q : queries) {
        
        url += q.first;
        url += q.second.data();
    }
    return url;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s", get_url().data());
}
```

(As you can see I already tried to put parantheses around the string literals to no avail)

Comment: Why the use of `piecewise_construct`?

Comment: Why are you using `std::piecewise_construct`? Just remove those and your code compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::piecewise_construct` constructor (as you are trying to use here for the `std::pair` construction) expects the rest of the arguments to be `std::tuple`s with each tuple holding the arguments to construct one of the pieces (e.g. pair elements).

You are not passing tuples as second and third parameter, so it can't work. It should be

```
queries.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct,
                     std::forward_as_tuple("key="),
                     std::forward_as_tuple(params.key_));
```

However, if you want construction of each pair element from just one argument, you don't need the piecewise constructor. `std::pair` has a constructor specifically for that:

```
queries.emplace_back("key=", params.key_);
```

None of this has anything to do with whether or not the array is decayed to a pointer. (It will be decayed where that is required, no manual intervention required.)

Comment: I guess I never really understood that till now thanks